# java reflection to invoke a method that takes a Comparable[] argument

Tags: java, reflection, comparable

I have a class with a `static` method which takes a `Comparable[]` as argument.

I need to find and invoke the method .I tried the following with `java reflection`

```
class X{

    public static void sort(Comparable[] a){
        System.out.println("sorting");
    }
    public static void read(String name){
        System.out.println("name="+name);
    }
}

...
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SecurityException, NoSuchMethodException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, InstantiationException {
        String[] a= new String[]{"E","X","A","M","P","L","E"};
        Class xc = Class.forName("my.javacode.X");

        Method m2 = xc.getMethod("read", java.lang.String.class);
        m2.invoke(null, "jon");

        Method m1 = xc.getMethod("sort", Comparable[].class);
        System.out.println(m1);
        m1.invoke(null, a);

    }
..
```

this produced an exception

```
name=jon
public static void my.javacode.X.sort(java.lang.Comparable[])
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at my.javacode.Misc.main(Misc.java:36)
```

Any idea how to correct this? The Comparable[].class argument in getMethod() returns the correct method object..However the invoke fails when the String[] is passed..I am trying to implement sort() as generic method sothat it can work for arrays of Wrapper types..(like Integer[],Double[],String[] etc)

Any advice/correction appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you call [`Method.invoke`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...%29) with this signature:

```
public Object invoke(Object obj, Object... args)
```

... the varargs parameter is only used *as* a varargs parameter when it would fail otherwise.

So this call:

```
m2.invoke(null, "jon");
```

is equivalent to:

```
m2.invoke(null, new Object[] {"jon"});
```

But `String[]` is implicitly convertible to `Object[]`, so this call:

```
m1.invoke(null, a);
```

is *not* expanded to wrap `a` in an `Object[]`. It's trying to call the method as if it's got 7 string parameters rather than one array parameter.

Two options:

- Declare `a` as type `Object` rather than `String[]`, which will then make the compiler perform the wrapping for you.
- *Explicitly* wrap it in an array:

  ```
  m1.invoke(null, new Object[] { a });
  ```

Either should be fine.